# What is the purpose of `__metaclass__ = type`?

Tags: python, package, python-2.x, metaclass

Python (2 only?) looks at the value of variable `__metaclass__` to determine how to create a `type` object from a class definition. [It is possible to define `__metaclass__` at the module or package level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023932/python-metaclasses-at-module-level), in which case it applies to all subsequent class definitions in that module.

However, I encountered the following in the [`flufl.enum`](http://pythonhosted.org/flufl.enum/) package's [`__init__.py`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~barry/flufl.enum/trunk/view/98/flufl/enum/__init__.py#L23):

```
__metaclass__ = type
```

Since the default metaclass if `__metaclass__` is not defined is `type`, wouldn't this have no effect? (This assignment would revert to the default if `__metaclass__` were assigned to at a higher scope, but I see no such assignment.) What is its purpose?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In Python 2, a declaration `__metaclass__ = type` makes declarations that would otherwise create old-style classes create new-style classes instead. Only old-style classes use a module level `__metaclass__` declaration. New-style classes inherit their metaclass from their base class (e.g. `object`), unless `__metaclass__` is provided as a class variable.

The declaration is not actually used in the code you linked to above (there are no class declarations in the `__init__.py` file), but it could be. I suspect it was included as part of some boilerplate that makes Python 2 code work more like Python 3 (where all classes are always new-style).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it has no effect.  It's probably just a misunderstanding from `flufl.enum`'s author, or a leftover from previous code.

A "superpackage" `__metaclass__` declaration would have no effect because there is no such a thing as Python superpackages.